# My boot screen for Lubuntu doesn't load correctly. How can I fix that? Thanks!

Tags: dual-boot

This would be my first post and I am not proficient in Linux, although I do use it regularly as a layperson.

I just dual-booted my old laptop with XP and Lubuntu (I have an emotional attachment to XP). However, the boot screen for Lubuntu doesn't load correctly. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that you have the correct graphic drivers for your hardware should fix the boot splash animation.